# Double a column values when a different column equals a specified value

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I want to double the value in the distance column in the rows which have the value of 'one-way' in the hike_type column. I am iterating through the df and finding all of the proper rows but I am having trouble getting the multiplication to stick.

This is finding the proper rows but will not put the change into effect

```
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    if row['hike_type'] == 'one-way':
        row['distance'] * 2
```

This hasn't worked either

```
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    if row['hike_type'] == 'one-way':
       row['distance'] = row['distance'] * 2
```

for some reason when I do (below) it prints what I want.

```
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    if row['hike_type'] == 'one-way':
       print(row['distance'] * 2)
```

Comment: could you add an example of your input dataframe, and the desired output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIUC, what you want could be achieved with just one line as below

```
df['distance']= np.where (df['hike_type'] == 'one-way', df['distance'].astype(int)*2,df['distance'])
```

OR you can use `df.loc` as below

```
df.update(df.loc[df['hike_type'] == 'one-way','distance'].astype(int)*2)
```

OR

```
df.update(df[df['hike_type'] == 'one-way']['distance'].astype(int)*2)
```

Comment: Nailed it, thanks! Only changes I made was changed df['distance2'] to df['distance'] so that changes were applied to the same column and .astype(int) to .astype(float). Thanks for the help